# Referencing a File path and worksheet name in excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

Currently I have a file path in Excel called `C:\Desktop\[Data.xlsm]Sheet1`. It works fine with the full file path but I would like to separate `[Data.xlsm]` Sheet1 into 2 separate excel cells eg. `[Data.xlsm]` in cell A1 and Sheet1 in cell B1 such that the file path would appear to be something like that `C:\Desktop\"A1"&"B1"` .

Would like to know if it's possible without the use of VB.

Comment: What are you doing with the file path?  It's difficult to say if you can make it work without VBA if we don't know what "work" looks like.

Comment: Well currently what works is =SUM('C:\Desktop\[Data.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$43:$F$44) which gives me the value that I need eg 389. But I would like to separate [Data.xlsm]Sheet1 into 2 different cells as mentioned above such that instead of a fixed file path, I have a dynamic file path.

Answer (score 0):

If you separate the file path into different cells, then you will need to use Indirect() to stitch it together again. Unfortunately, Indirect() only works when the referenced file is already open, which defeats the purpose of dynamically constructed file names.

As an alternative to Indirect, you can use Indirect.Ext, which is included in the free [morefunc.dll](http://download.cnet.com/Morefunc/3000-2077_4-10423159.html) add-in, but it will not work with some versions of Excel. IRRC it does not work with 64 bit Excel.

Comment: Unfortunately am running on a 64 bit Excel so the add-in option might not work. Any other possible solutions?

Comment: No, sorry. Not without VBA.